# Como evito loopings infinitos em uma matriz?

Tags: java, matriz

"Monte uma matriz F de tamanho n x n representando uma floresta. Cada elemento dessa matriz pode ter 3 valores:

0 – se estiver vazio 
1 – se contém uma árvore 
2 – se contém fogo

Com probabilidade p, dada pelo usuário, coloque uma árvore em cada posição de F (utilize `Math.random()`). Escolha uma árvore para incendiar (altere seu valor para 2).

Aplique a seguinte regra até que não exista mais elementos com valor 2:

- Se existe uma árvore na posição (i,j) e existe um fogo em alguma posição vizinha, mude árvore para fogo.
- Se existe fogo em uma posição (i,j) e não existe árvore na vizinhança, mude fogo para vazio.

Determine a porcentagem de árvores que sobreviveram."

Ouso dizer que consegui fazer funcionar. Aqui está meu código:

```
package aula10;
import java.util.*;
public class aula10_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, i, j;
        double p;
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        ent.useLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("Digite a dimensão da matriz (que é quadrada):");
        n = ent.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite a probabilidade de haver uma árvore em qualquer ponto da floresta:");
        p = ent.nextDouble();
        int [][] F = new int[n][n];
        Random rnd = new Random();        
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                F[i][j] = rnd.nextInt();
                if (F[i][j] < p) {
                    F[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    F[i][j] = 0;
                }
                System.out.print(F[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
        int k = rnd.nextInt(n-1);
        int l = rnd.nextInt(n-1);
        while (true) {
        if (F[k][l] == 1) {
            F[k][l] = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(F));

    }

}
```

Testei diversas vezes e entrou em looping infinito algumas. Com o Debug eu consegui identificar e corrigir alguns erros, mas mesmo assim às vezes dá problema com probabilidades pequenas. Não sei exatamente o que acontece... Meus conhecimentos em Java são limitadíssimos, então me dei por satisfeita com esse código. Mas ainda aceito sugestões de melhoria.

Answer (score 1):

Dada uma posição `i,j` na floresta, os vizinhos dessa posição são:

```
F[i-1][j-1]
F[i-1][j]
F[i-1][j+1]
F[i][j-1]
F[i][j+1]
F[i+1][j-1]
F[i+1][j]
F[i+1][j+1]
```

A cada posição que você percorre na floresta, ou seja, para cada `(i,j)` dentro do `for` mais interno (o `for j`), você tem que verificar cada um dos vizinhos pelas condições propostas no problema (tomando o cuidado de não verificar fora da área da floresta, ou seja, limitando-se a `i-1 >=0`, `j-1 >= 0`, `i+1 < n` e `j+1 < n`).

Você deve repetir esses `for i` e `for j` enquanto houver alguma árvore pegando fogo.

Comment: Mas aí no caso eu devo fazer for (i=-1; i>=0; i++) e o mesmo para o for j? Ou essa instrução entra em algum if?

Comment: Crie uma função que recebe `x, y, valorASubstituir, valorNovo`. Dentro dela teste se x, y saem da área da floresta, se saírem você não faz nada, senão troca o item da posição x, y de valorASubstituir para valorNovo.

Comment: Eu ainda não aprendi funções no curso, então não sei se a professora aceitaria uma resolução utilizando um recurso que ainda não aprendemos em sala. Meus conhecimentos em java são limitadíssimos e as aulas são muito triviais, mas os exercícios são monstruosos (opinião de todos os alunos da turma). Mesmo assim, agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Neste caso o jeito é fazer sem funções mesmo. Antes de tentar alterar uma posição vizinha à posição atual, teste com `if`s se as coordenadas da vizinha saem da área da floresta.

Comment: Acho que consegui, depois de dias trabalhando nisso... Não está perfeito, muito menos prático, mas acho que funciona. Sintam-se livres para verificar se deu certo mesmo e se o código pode ser melhorado. Muito obrigada pela ajuda! :)

Comment: Poste o código para olharmos. Se a resposta fornecida foi satisfatória, não esqueça de aceitá-la conforme mostrado [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/357).

Comment: Eu alterei o código na própria pergunta. Está atualizado.

Comment: O problema é que às vezes entra em looping infinito por alguma razão...

Comment: Não acho que seja assim que o programa deva funcionar. Você começou bem, com um `for j` dentro de um `for i` para montar a floresta. Mas precisa voltar a executar essa dupla de `for` encadeados para os outros dois passos do programa, que são espalhar o fogo e testar se o fogo apagou. E a escolha da árvore inicial que vai pegar fogo não deve ser feita dentro de um `while` como você fez (corrigir isso também vai evitar o loop infinito, que é devido à condição do `break` nunca ocorrer).